# How to create compass plot graph in Excel?

Tags: excel, graph

I really enjoy the format of the political compass I have seen online, I was wondering if it's possible to create my own using x and y axis?

[image]

Here are my data that I wish to graph:

```
"Stamford,  CT",-38,-25
"Atlanta,  GA",-31,-37
"Melbourne,  FL",-27,-38
"Huntsville,  AL",-26,-39
"Houston,  TX",-28,-32
"San Jose,  CA",-39,-15
"Oakland,  CA",-34,-14
"Fairfax,  VA",-33,-7
"Pensacola,  FL",-16,-28
"Dallas,  TX",-14,-33
"Hartford,  CT",-29,-10
"Detroit,  MI",-18,-35
"New Haven,  CT",-25,-27
"Chicago,  IL",-30,-11
"Lansing,  MI",-12,-36
"Charlotte,  NC",-23,-22
"Savannah,  GA",-17,-34
"Wilmington,  NC",-19,-13
"Brooklyn,  NY",-36,25
"Saint Louis,  MO",-11,-23
"Spokane,  WA",9,-31
"Ann Arbor,  MI",-13,-19
"West Palm Beach,  FL",-9,0
"Baltimore,  MD",-20,2
"Bellingham,  WA",1,-4
"Boston,  MA",-32,20
"Jacksonville,  FL",7,-21
"Columbus,  OH",-6,-16
"Medford,  OR",-8,-30
"San Antonio,  TX",14,-24
"Fort Lauderdale,  FL",-2,1
"Seattle,  WA",-21,23
"Memphis,  TN",16,-26
"Sacramento,  CA",-15,7
"New York,  NY",-37,34
"Kansas City,  MO",8,-17
"San Francisco,  CA",-35,35
"Akron,  OH",19,-29
"Austin,  TX",0,5
"Orlando,  FL",17,-1
"Los Angeles,  CA",-22,18
"Raleigh,  NC",-1,3
"Iowa City,  IA",6,-20
"Greenville,  SC",4,-2
"Princeton,  NJ",-24,31
"Cincinnati,  OH",3,14
"Tampa,  FL",26,-8
"Miami,  FL",2,21
"Des Moines,  IA",5,4
"Grand Rapids,  MI",11,10
"Portland,  OR",-7,15
"Denver,  CO",-3,17
"Asheville,  NC",-4,24
"Oklahoma City,  OK",24,-18
"Reno,  NV",31,-6
"Indianapolis,  IN",23,-12
"Milwaukee,  WI",13,-3
"Salt Lake City,  UT",18,-9
"San Diego,  CA",-10,27
"Cleveland,  OH",20,22
"Tucson,  AZ",29,-5
"Fresno,  CA",10,11
"New Orleans,  LA",21,9
"Las Vegas,  NV",30,13
"Irvine,  CA",-5,32
"Phoenix,  AZ",28,6
"Madison,  WI",15,19
"Buffalo,  NY",27,12
"Burlington,  VT",12,33
"Albuquerque,  NM",32,8
"Pittsburgh,  PA",25,29
"Louisville,  KY",33,16
"Minneapolis,  MN",22,28
"Boise,  ID",36,26
"Rochester,  NY",35,30
"Anchorage,  AK",34,36
"Honolulu,  HI",37,37
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to create dummy values, for example the table below:

```
A   B
1   5
2   4
3   3
4   2
5   1
-1  -5
-2  -4
-3  -3
-4  -2
-5  -1
```

would produce the following graph:
[image: compass]

You would have to decide how to transform your values, whether certain values should be converted to negatives or whether it would be better to standardise them and manipulate the axis placement. In a word, the task boils down to manufacturing a distribution where values fell in proportional distances from some arbitrary point where you want for your axis to be, zero in my example.

Comment: Yup, somewhat clumsily did it.  Too bad there is nothing built in.